# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS sometimes messes up new lines in shell

Tags: command-line, 22.04

Here's an image of what I see sometimes when I run my script:

[image]

Here's an image of the same script, when it works correctly:

[image]

This happens sometimes. Maybe 20 or 30 percent.

Any ideas why it happens and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

This is called "staircase effect", and is caused by the lack of LF -> CR LF (aka `\n` -> `\r\n`) conversion as the data goes through the kernel towards the terminal.

Applications are supposed to emit `\n`, but that causes the terminal to move the cursor to the next line, without returning to the first column. The terminal needs a `\r` as well to return there. The conversion happens (or not) in the kernel's tty handling (line discipline), subject to the ONLCR flag.

Compare the output of `stty` when the terminal behaves normally vs. when it misbehaves, I'm pretty certain you'll see a `-onlcr` entry appearing.

Restore the normal behavior by executing `stty onlcr`.

(For further details, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151963)

I cannot tell what is the reason for this incorrect setting occurring in the first place. Could be a bug in bash-5.2, not properly restoring the stty settings (bash needs to toggle them back and forth when executing a command versus when waiting for the next command to be typed it). Or could be that another application that you launched previously leaves the terminal in this state (maybe after an unclean exit, such as `^C`). Keep an eye on what action on your part triggers this behavior, and let us know if you figure out something.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, and `stty` already has `onlcr` enabled. I solved (temporarily) by using `unbuffer` from the `expect` package like this:

```
unbuffer ./script.sh
```

F.

Comment: I have used this temporary solution as my permanent work-around.